# Constrain function input type using string variable

Tags: typescript

I have a few simple types:

```js
export const structureTypes = ["atom", "molecule"] as const
export type Structure = typeof structureTypes[number]
export const atomTypes = [
  "hydrogen",
  "oxygen",
  "argon",
] as const
export const moleculeTypes = [
  "water",
  "methane",
] as const
export type AtomType = typeof atomTypes[number]
export type MoleculeType = typeof moleculeTypes[number]
```

I would like to be able to use these to constrain the possible inputs of an object that holds the IDs of each type:

```js
export type StructureIdCache = {
  [key in Structure as string]: {
    [key in AtomType | MoleculeType]: string
  }
}
```

This works, but allowing `AtomType | MoleculeType` on the 2nd level allows me to use `"water"` as a key when the 1st level key is `"atom"` which is invalid. How can I modify the types to allow input of only allowable names in the 2nd level of the object?

I have tried creating a conditional type:

```js
export type StructureType<T> = T extends Atom ? AtomType : MoleculeType
```

This works for creating specific types:

```js
type AtomTypeNames = StructureType<Atom>
type MoleculeTypeNames = StructureType<Molecule>
```

But does not allow me to constrain the inputs for a function:

```js
export const getTypeId = async (
  c: Context,
  type: Structure,
  name: StructureType<typeof type> // <-- this should restrict name inputs but does not
): Promise<string> => {
  // do something
}
```

How can I restrict the valid inputs for `name`, based on the value of the string passed to `type`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr82zW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, yes that seems to work based on your test cases at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to proceed is to write out a single [`const`-asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) object whose type captures the desired relationship between your `Structure` and associated `AtomType`/`MoleculeType`:

```
const structures = {
  atom: ["hydrogen", "oxygen", "argon"],
  molecule: ["water", "methane"]
} as const;
```

And use it to generate a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) representing this relationship:

```
type StructureType = { 
  [K in keyof typeof structures]: typeof structures[K][number] 
};
    
/* type StructureType = {
    readonly atom: "hydrogen" | "oxygen" | "argon";
    readonly molecule: "water" | "methane";
} */
```

And now, instead of trying to make your [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function depend on a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), which is essentially opaque to the compiler and difficult for it to reason about, you make it depend on an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) corresponding to a property lookup:

```
export const getTypeId = async <K extends keyof StructureType>(
  type: K,
  name: StructureType[K]
): Promise<string> => {
  return null!
}
```

So `type` is some key type `K` of `StructureType` (that is, either `"atom"` or `"molecule"`), and `name` is the corresponding property type `StructureType[K]` of `StructureType` (so, for example if `K` is `"atom"`, then `StructureType[K]` is `"hydrogen" | "oxygen" | "argon").  You're not necessarily actually looking up a property in an object, but the compiler can reason fairly well about generic object lookups, and by phrasing the operation in those terms it compiles without error.

---

Let's try it out:

```
getTypeId("atom", "hydrogen"); // okay
getTypeId("atom", "water"); // error
getTypeId("molecule", "water"); // okay
```

Looks good.  In the first and second cases, `K` is inferred as `"atom`", and so `"hydrogen"` is acceptable but `"water"` is not.  In the third case, `K` is inferred as `"molecule"`, and so `"water"` is acceptable.  So the relationship between `type` and `name` is enforced, at least for these use cases.

(There are some situations where `K` is inferred as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and then `StructureType[K]` will also be a union, and the relationship might not be enforced the way you want.  But this sort of issue is usually not a big deal for most users of generic functions, so I won't digress into a discussion of how to deal with that here.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOBXYVHwKYRgXhgbwCgYYBDKEAWwC4YBtAIgAsBPAE3hAHN0x6AaGPRAAPZt14D6JeJ3D0AunyIwKIADbpgiDTQYB3Munj9BFdFEYkw6BQQC+pLKEhQA3AQJRmAB3QwAylBIKGjoACo+frh4dADSMACWYDAA1ujMIABmMF6+WXBByKgYEPI0uej5CEWhELSx8rRgiBQARkbyMHbuAPQAVDmRAYUhGBG+OPjKxBgkrOBqzKTk1IIs7Fw89DAAPoIiYlu7gtKyvO7EM+hzC0uqGlo6ggZQRtt79GYWVjbuDn09DzoYTeEDwWDOaAwbhQcboACSrEmJAgzDAwBgAB54sDXmBWFg0hlsoFgsVwpEAHwACmUFRosSUxDAJDMNFJNTGkXq8gIAEoaAAFDgUBIQdCYhBJTiUnCywhXYrJZpqNQAQnsHhhcMR1KkKxMTDYHHE9D5rhgPR6MBAKRIzAI2siuv1lENLze5st1qMHHgjvMOtYevumm0NkkHuMXqtNrtzCAA)